# Instantiating Prefabs at run time

Tags: unity, assets, prefabs

I'm trying to move my project to Addressables and upload assets, prefabs and screens to an archive on the server. 
I'm a new in Unity and this a bit challenging for me. 
I've prepared all prefabs for addressable usage and now I'm trying load them.

All my prefabs have loads throw `GameObject.Instantiate`
For example:

```
    public class PlatformObject : LocationObject
        {
//other properties and methods
            public PlatformObject Clone()
            {
                var clone = ((Runner.PlatformObject)GameObject.Instantiate(this));
                clone.Id = this.Id;
                clone.NextPlatforms = this.NextPlatforms;
                clone.IsStartPlatform = this.IsStartPlatform;
                clone.Level = this.Level;
                clone.Type = this.Type;
                clone.MinimumDistance = this.MinimumDistance;
                clone.AllowDispose = false;
                clone.Size = this.Size;
                return clone;
            }
    }
```

I've tried change this code for usage `Addressables`.

```
public async Task<PlatformObject> Clone()
        {
            var handle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(this.name);
            var clone = (await handle.Task).GetComponent<PlatformObject>();
            clone.Id = this.Id;
            clone.NextPlatforms = this.NextPlatforms;
            clone.IsStartPlatform = this.IsStartPlatform;
            clone.Level = this.Level;
            clone.Type = this.Type;
            clone.MinimumDistance = this.MinimumDistance;
            clone.AllowDispose = false;
            clone.Size = this.Size;
            return clone;
        }
```

I've got a cloned object successfully, but object doesn't appears on the scene. Looks like object not initialized properly, bcouz I've got a lot of warnings like that:

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is
>   disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'Mid_Town_07').
>   UnityEngine.Transform:set_parent(Transform)

I've googled and have found a few solution related with parent location. 
Made changed but it didn't help. I'm still getting those warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to also Instantiate the object before setting it's parent transform as it's not yet an instance when you call LoadAssetAsync.

See the docs here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.1/manual/AddressableAssetsGettingStarted.html

Notably this line:

```
Addressables.InstantiateAsync("AssetAddress");
```

Or alternatively once you have the GameObject, instantiate it as normal.